# How can i maintain a temperature of 5k on a super conducting wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, temperature, superconductivity

I have bought nb/ti low temperature superconducting wire , so i can make a superconducting magnet, my liquid nitrogen supplier is ready to meet my needs but , i need to maintain that temperature in order to maintain superconductivity , and evade a supermagnetic "quench". so what should i do , how can i make a cryostat since all of them online are medical and not only a container .
thank you , if you cannot answer the question please post an yinsight on the issue i am a highschool student and way over my head

Comment: Liquid nitrogen is $77\,\mathrm{K}$. If you need $5\,\mathrm{K}$, you're going to need something cooler...

Comment: liquid helium then ? because they alwas use liquid nitrogen to cool them?

Comment: Who is "they" and how do you know that they "always" use LN2. That said, you can buy demo-sized samples of high-temp superconductors pretty easily these days and those will do their thing at LN2 temps.

Comment: How about getting a low-temperature boiling liquid, immerse the superconducting coil in that liquid, and control the pressure in the vapor space above that liquid?

Comment: 5K is a really low temperature. Don't see any realistic way for you to get from liquid nitrogen temperature to 5K, and liquid helium is very expensive (and has handling and safety issues considerably above those of liquid-N2). If you want to experiment with superconductivity, then as dmckee said I think the best option would be get some high-Tc superconductor with a critical temperature above 77K so that you can use liquid-N2.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need liquid helium. Liquid nitrogen only goes down to about 77K. What's your purpose for a superconducting magnet? I think this will help people give you better answers. To make a cryostat, you'll need a vacuum jacket/insulating layer (do you have access to a machine shop?) to isolate the region with liquid helium from room temperature, otherwise it will just boil off. (It will still boil off, but not immediately.) In general, the purpose of a cryostat is to keep an object (superconducting magnet, some sample being measured) at low temperature. Like in a thermos, the space with the cryogen is isolated from atmosphere to keep it cold. This is why you can essentially carry liquid nitrogen in thermoses.

A liquid helium bath at 4.2K will do the trick to keep Nb/Ti superconducting, but LHe is very expensive. Depending on how much money you're willing to spend, many scientific manufacturers sell cryogenic dewars/vacuum flasks.